# Select en Consulta con LinQ Dynamic

Tags: asp.net-core, linq-to-sql

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta con LinQ Dynamic ya que el Select de la consulta varía en tiempo de ejecución.

En un principio, pensaba que mi necesidad se podía resolver de otro modo pero, tras varias consultas en este foro, al final he llegado a la conclusión de que lo más apropiado es usar LinQ Dynamic.

En primer lugar habría que declarar y definir la variable que va a armar el Select de la consulta LinQ. Sería algo así pero así no es porque no funciona. Quisiera saber cual es la forma correcta de definirla.

```
            var miSelect = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda("Id = d.Id, Titulo = d.Titulo, Autor = d.Autor, Editorial = d.Editorial");
```

Haciendo esto, Visual Studio me dice que ParseLambda no es correcto. Dice que "Ninguna sobrecarga para el método ParseLambda toma 1 argumentos"

Una vez definida esta variable, la pasaríamos en el Select de la consulta LinQ, pero también de forma correcta.

```
            Libros miConsulta = (from d in db.Libros

                                 where d.Id == id
                                 select new Libros { miSelect }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Espero haberme explicado bien y agradezco a quién me pueda echar una mano con esto que llevo varios días dándole vueltas y no avanzo.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Porque el select varia en tiempo de ejecución ?

Comment: El motivo de querer hacer esto asi, es porque quiero hacer una sóla consulta que me sirva para distintos escenarios. y dependiendo del escenario, me muestre sólo unos campos u otros. Y los escenarios pueden variar dependiendo del item que se seleccione en un desplegable, del usuario que esté manejando la aplicación, etc...